# Force instantiation of friend functions

Tags: c++, templates

Assume we have a template class with friend function:

```
template<class T>
class A {
    friend A operator+ (int, const A&);
};
```

This function is implemented somewhere below:

```
template<class T>
A<T> operator+ (int i, const A<T>& a) {
    ...
}
```

And also there is force instantiation of class template further below:

```
template class A<int>;
```

Does this imply that `operator+(int, A<int>)` will be compiled? Or do I have to force instantiate it separately to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Template parameters aren't automatically forwarded to `friend` declarations. You need to specify a template parameter for the function as well:

```
template<class T>
class A {
    template<class U>
    friend A<U> operator+ (int, const A<U>&);
};
```

Implementation is almost correct, should be

```
template<class T>
A<T> operator+ (int i, const A<T>& a) {
                           // ^^^
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Amusing for some reason that this doesn't actually answer the question ;p

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Doesn't it? Enlighten me please.

Comment: Thank you for correcting implementation, fixed it in the question.

Comment: Actually template friend is not exactly the same thing as I've posted, for it makes **all** `operator+(int, A<U>)` friends with `A<T>`. Am I right assuming `friend A<T> operator+ (int, const A<T>&)` is also correct declaration?

Comment: The OP is asking whether the `friend` function template needs to be explicitly instantiated or whether that'll occur as part of `A`'s instantiation. You instead taught the OP (correctly) that the `friend` function template declaration is broken. I can't see how the two are the same.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, such is the outcome for asking for XY-Problems ;-)